# Conflicting keep-alive and idle timeouts

Tags: apache, timeout, amazon-elb, keep-alive

I have an AWS Application Load Balancer with Apache HTTP 2.4 behind it. I've been getting sporatic 502 errors, and I think I've determined that it's because of the Event MPM module. When I switched to the Worker MPM module, the 502s went away. My trouble now is finding the optimal settings for the various timeouts from the ALB -> Apache -> Tomcat.

I have long-running APIs that are meant to be called system-to-system. They may take up to 15 minutes, and the client needs to wait for the response, so **I've set the idle timeout on the load balancer to 900 seconds**. This app also serves **sub-second** requests too.

I've read through [this AWS article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/apache-backend-elb/), which essentially says every subsequent downstream timeout needs to be higher than the previous timeout. (ALB idle timeout < Apache keep-alive timeout < Tomcat proxy timeout)

However, in the [KeepAliveTimeout httpd documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#keepalivetimeout), it says:

> Setting KeepAliveTimeout to a high value may cause performance problems in heavily loaded servers. The higher the timeout, the more server processes will be kept occupied waiting on connections with idle clients.

That seems contradictory to the AWS article.
What values should I set for the `Timeout` and `KeepAliveTimeout` Apache directives?

Answer (score 0):

Because your application should only be communicating with the limited number of load balancing servers (rather than lots of public clients), there is less risk of exhausting resources through creating lots of server processes.

As such, provided you're behind a load balancer, it's reasonable to set the `Timeout` and `KeepAliveTimeout` high.